# Finding minimum weight perfect matchings in sparse bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, perfect-matchings

> **Question:**
>   What can be recommended for finding optimal perfect matchings in large bipartite graphs with small vertex degree if the edge-weights are positive real values?

I am looking for algorithms of which freely available implementations exist or that don't require heavy machinery for implementation.

Apart from that I am also looking for graph modifications that can speed up the calculation of the optimal matching edges; subtracting vertex potentials may be in that vein.

Comment: The fractional matching polytope is equal to the matching polytope for bipartite graphs, so you can just solve a small linear program.

Answer (score 1):

[pyMCFSimplex](https://github.com/sommergis/pymcfsimplex) seems to best fit my needs.
"*It is a free Python port of a Python Wrapper for MCFSimplex. pyMCFimplex is a Python-Wrapper for the C++ MCFSimplex Solver Class from the Operations Research Group at the University of Pisa. MCFSimplex is a piece of software hat solves big sized Minimum Cost Flow Problems very fast through the (primal or dual) network simplex algorithm.*"

[scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching.html) is an alternative